# regex to get string between slash's

Tags: regex, templates, toolkit

Im using template toolkit, but I believe the regexp works the same as js.

given a string, for e.g:  /home/views/register/success or /home/views/register.tt

how do I get the string after (and including) 'views/' upto the next '/' or '.', giving me in this case 'views/register'

something like:

```
var template_name = template.name.match('views/'+REGEXP);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(views/[^./]*)` should do the trick.

I'm not sure if you need to escape the dot. If the abore regex doesn't work try adding a backslash before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
(views\/((?!\/|\.).)*)
```

ie. `views/` followed by any character other than `/` or a `.`